# UTF-8 decoding library

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, unicode-string

I have to code in an application which is in Unicode UTF-8 in Windows, MSVC 10. I'm aware that the UTF-8 encoded strings would use either 1 or 2 bytes per character. So, my question is : Is std::string suitable for this? If yes, how do I decode the strings? As far as I understand std::string is just an array of bytes and it doesn't provide any decoding logic. 
How can I know the logical length of the string? How can I extract logical characters from a string? Are there any libraries which helps me to extract logical characters from the string?

e.g : If I have the string "olé" in std::string, I need to know that the length is 3, but not 4.

Comment: UTF-8 can use up to 4 bytes per character, not just one or two.

Comment: What [exactly](http://utf8everywhere.org/#faq.glossary) you mean by decoding the string? More importantly is why do you need to know the length? It usually makes no sense in Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A commonally used  library is  [ICU - International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `std::string` is appropriare but as you’ve noticed it only operates on bytes, not Unicode code points. In that, `std::string` is an opaque type; this isn’t necessarily bad (in fact, it does have some advantages, see the links below for information) but it makes it necessary to decode the string if you need information about characters.

For the actual handling of UTF-8 (where necessary), you can use the [Boost.NoWide](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/) library to decode UTF-8.

Furthermore, I suggest reading the [UTF-8 everywhere manifesto](http://utf8everywhere.org/) for some information about the use of UTF-8 vs. other Unicode transformations.

Comment: std::string makes it really hard to sort strings and test characters in all sorts of ways. Not if you don't need such, that's indeed possible to use UTF-8 strings using std::string. You could also make use of QString (Qt) or CString (MFC...).

Comment: Thanks @Konrad Rudolph for providing the links. They were useful... From the initial glance, it looks like the Boost.Nowide library doesn't have a stringstream... but, I need to look in detail.

Comment: @Alexis For that you can (indeed, *must*) provide custom comparers. That isn’t restricted to `std::string` though, it’s even true when working with wide characters due to the presence of combining characters etc.

Comment: I dont think you can get the count of unicode code points in a string using Boost.NoWide or can you (only if all of them are in the BMP)? I see that Boost.NoWide is useful for I/O, but it does not offer functionality for unicode string handling otherwise.

Comment: I found this amusing from the article: "Windows C++ programmers are educated that Unicode must be done with ‘widechars’. As a result of this mess, they are now among the most confused ones about what is the right thing to do about text". I'm one of them !!

Answer (score -2):

First you may want to call the mbstowcs() function to transform the UTF-8 characters to wide characters. Then if you want the result to be 8 bits, you'll have a loss of data in the event you have "Unicode" characters (characters outside of the ISO-8859-1 plane, also called Latin 1.)

Note that the "Windows" encoding is not 1 to 1 equivalent to ISO-8859-1, but in most cases ISO-8859-1 is what people use these days.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/mbstowcs/

Okay, if you just want the length in characters, use the mblen() function:

```
len = mblen(str.c_str(), str.length());
```

Additional note: an easy way to implementation mblen() is to count the number of bytes that are not between 0x80 and 0xBF since those are part of a multi-bytes sequence. This is particularly useful if you receive a UTF-8 byte sequence over a flaky serial connection.

Comment: "in most cases ISO-8859-1 is what people use these days". On the interwebs, I see CP1252 mislabelled as ISO-8859-1 fairly frequently. Not sure which one you'd say they were "using" in that case, but it pretty much doesn't matter what "most people" are using, what matters is the minority of people whose text breaks your code ;-)

Comment: That’s not what OP wants. Why would he want to convert UTF-16 losslessly to single-byte codepoints? The question doesn’t imply this anywhere. Mention of ISO-8859-1 is just misguided. “in most cases [it’s] what people use these days” is completely wrong. In fact, modern browsers actually use a different encoding *even if* you explicitly request this encoding because almost nobody ever means ISO-8859-1, even if they say so.

Comment: Or how about converting to utf-16 or utf-32 for internal processing.

Comment: First of all, I did not say UTF-16. On Windows they use UCS-2. They don't know what UTF-16 is. Second, the first plane of Unicode is ISO-8859-1, whatever you say, that's what it is. Third, CP1252 is specific to Windows and if you convert from UTF-8 you're not going to get CP1252 which is why I mention that you get ISO-8859-1. Then it's your problem to properly select the correct font to render the text later. If you know what encoding you have, you can do it.

Comment: Yes, the first 256 characters of UCS-2 are the same as UCS-4, UTF-16 and UTF-8 once converted. They're all ISO-8859-1. Converting to another encoding (such as CP1252) requires tables or a library such as iconv (which I recommend you avoid!)

Comment: @Alexis Wilke: "Once converted", correct. Oh, by the way, "what people use these days", IF they're still using an 8-byte codepage, is usually ISO-8859-15. That might change once the Euro currency is history, but ATM Latin-1 is "common" because people cannot remember it's actually Latin-9...

Comment: Hmmm... the EURO character is found in ISO-8859-15, -16, and -7. Not -9. Anyway, with Unicode and the Internet, ISO-8859-1 is what you hear about because all the other 8 bit encodings are not represented 1 to 1 with any other plane in Unicode.